# XML - DTD - Content error in the external subset

Tags: xml, parsing, dtd

I'm trying to validate following .dtd code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PERSON [

<!ELEMENT lista_plac_dokument (autor, informacje_o_dokumencie, zatrudnieni)>
    <!ELEMENT autor (autor_imię, autor_nazwisko, autor_adres+)>
        <!ELEMENT autor_imię   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT autor_nazwisko   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT autor_adres (ulica,(kod_pocztowy|zip),miasto,kraj)>
        <!ELEMENT ulica  (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT kod_pocztowy  (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT miasto   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT kraj   (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT informacje_o_dokumencie (kategoria_dokumentu)>
        <!ELEMENT kategoria_dokumentu   (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT zatrudnieni (osoba*)>

    <!ELEMENT osoba (imię, nazwisko, stanowisko, data_zatrudnienia, wynagrodzenie_brutto_12_miesięcy, informacje_osobiste+)>
        <!ATTLIST osoba osoba_id ID #REQUIRED>
        <!ELEMENT imię   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT nazwisko  (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT stanowisko   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT data_zatrudnienia   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT wynagrodzenie_brutto_12_miesięcy   (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT informacje_osobiste (wiek?)>
        <!ELEMENT wiek (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

but each time I'm trying to check the syntax of it with the usage of following command:

```
xmllint --loaddtd person.dtd person.xml --noout
```

I do obtain following error:

```
person.dtd:29: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
]>
  ^
person.dtd:2: parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!DOCTYPE PERSON [
^
person.dtd:2: parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!DOCTYPE PERSON [
^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.dtd` file (the external declaration subset) must only contain actual markup declarations (`<!ELEMENT ...>` and others). `<!DOCTYPE ... [` and `]>` is only used in an `.xml` file (an instance document).

Try removing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PERSON [
```

from the begin and

```
]>
```

from the end of your `.dtd` file.